# How to call a numbered sequence of covariates with paste in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset, paste

I have a number of columns that are numbered sequentially. e.g. `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, etc. I also have an indicator variable (`ind`) for control or treatment status for each observation. I want to conduct a series of t-tests for a difference-in-means between the treatment and control groups for each question. Rather than typing question-by-question, I'd like a loop that outputs the p-values from all the tests into a matrix.

I think that the problem is with how I'm using `paste()`. I think that I am failing to create an object that actually calls up the data. I think R is trying to run a t.test on the text, without connecting the text to the data that it is meant to reference.
strong text

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(NA,50,8))

colnames(data) <- c("q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6","q7","ind")

data[,"ind"]<- c(rep(0,25),rep(1,25))

set.seed(42)
data[,"q1"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q2"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q3"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q4"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q5"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q6"] <- rnorm(50)
data[,"q7"] <- rnorm(50)

results <- data.frame(matrix(NA,7,2))

## Attempt One
for(i in 1:7){
results[i,1] <- i
a <- paste0("data$q",i,"[data$ind==1]")
b <- paste0("data$q",i,"[data$ind==0]")
results[i,2] <- t.test(a,b)[3]
}

####
# Error in t.test.default(a, b) : not enough 'x' observations
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# 2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion


###Attempt Two
for(i in 1:7){
results[i,1] <- i
a <- get(paste0("data$q",i,"[data$ind==1]"))
b <- get(paste0("data$q",i,"[data$ind==0]"))
results[i,2] <- t.test(a,b)[3]
}

####
# Error in get(paste0("data$q", i, "[data$ind==1]")) : 
#  object 'data$q1[data$ind==1]' not found
```

I have found many discussions about how to *create* variable names with `paste` in R, but I'm looking for how to *call* a variable name with `paste` in R.
 1. [how to assign to the names() attribute of the value of a variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907896/how-to-assign-to-the-names-attribute-of-the-value-of-a-variable-in-r) 
 2. [How to name variables on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2679193/1364839)
 3. Accessing variables with a for loop, as attempted in "Attempt Two" above: [Change variable name in for loop using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16566799/1364839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to manipulate variables as character strings, that is a sure sign that you are barking up the wrong tree. Anytime you are tempted to use `get` or `assign`, think again, you're probably doing it wrong.

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2_
data_m <- melt(data,id.var = "ind")
ddply(data_m,.(variable),
      function(x) t.test(x$value[x$ind == 1],x$value[x$ind == 0])[[3]])
```

Or just:

```
lapply(data[,1:7],function(x) t.test(x[data$ind == 1],x[data$ind == 0])[[3]])
```

Comment: First time seeing `melt`. Very interesting. I'm wondering, the variables I'm interested in looping through are only a few from a much larger data frame. How will I use the approach above when I'm interested in looping through ~20 numerically sequenced variables in a dataset with ~300 columns?

Comment: @DTRM Simple, only melt a subset of your data frame. Same idea applies with `lapply` (or use `sapply` to get a vector rather than a list).

Comment: OK, thank you! I tried the `lapply` option, but I get this error:
  `not enough 'y' observations`

Any ideas?

Comment: @DTRM I'm not a mind reader. My code works flawlessly on the example you provided.